Ошибка настройки логирования
При нажатии /start в телеграме ничего не происходит.
import time
import asyncio
import logging


import aiogram
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters.command import Command

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.info)
bot = Bot(token="")

dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    #await message.answer("Hello!")
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_full_name = message.from_user.full_name
    logging.info(f'{user_id=} {user_full_name=} {time.asctime()}')
    await message.reply(f"Привет, {user_full_name}")

#def get_weather(city, open)

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

В терминале такой ответ:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s/Desktop/dl_testovoe_bot/testovoe.py", line 10, in <module>
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.info)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/logging/__init__.py", line 2137, in basicConfig
    root.setLevel(level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/logging/__init__.py", line 1514, in setLevel
    self.level = _checkLevel(level)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/logging/__init__.py", line 216, in _checkLevel
    raise TypeError("Level not an integer or a valid string: %r"
TypeError: Level not an integer or a valid string: <function info at 0x10521a480>


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с формулировки заголовка вопроса.

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.info)

TypeError: Level not an integer or a valid string: <function info at 0x10521a480>

Нужно таки различать большие и маленькие буквы:

logging.info - это функция, которая вызывается для осуществления логирования
logging.INFO - это константа, которую можно передавать при конфигурировании логирования

Поэтому правильный код должен выглядеть так:
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

Документация на стандартный модуль логирования.

Как Ваш вопрос связан с vs code? По ошибке видно, что проблема с logging.basicConfig(level=logging.info), попробуйте убрать данную строчку и проверить работает ли, так же рекомендую познакомиться с документацией https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/

Cпасибо, сработало)
